# JSONP - ajax request callback fails

Tags: jquery, node.js, cross-domain, jsonp

I'm pushing some data from one domain to other using `jsonp`. I'm getting data on the 2nd server and the process works fine. But the callback is not working properly.Even after getting the data on the other server the request is showing `pending` status and after sometime the request fails with error `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    crossDomain: true,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log('success')
    },
    error: function(xhr,status,error){
      console.log('error')
    }
});
```

When the request fails, I gets 'error in the console.

**Update** :

Headers

```
Request URL:http://example.com:3000/request?callback=jQuery21309164826604537666_1429167109185&firstname=sdf&lastname=sdf&_=1429167109187
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:*/*
Referer:http://localhost/widgets/form.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded
callback:jQuery21309164826604537666_1429167109185
firstname:sdf
lastname:sdf
phone:sdf
email:sdf
_:1429167109187
```

Comment: Are you sure that the response is in JSONP format?

Comment: Visit the URL in Chrome or FF and sniff the headers for us please.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You mean the response from the 2nd domain should be  in jsonp format ?

Comment: That's right. If it is not you cannot call it across domains using JS - you would need to use CORS (if supported) or a server-side proxy.

Comment: It's jsonp, not a CORS issue guys. I'm waiting on those headers.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan should I manunally pad the json in a function and return that ?

Comment: @Drakes how do you know that, given that OP hasn't mentioned the URL that he's calling?

Comment: @Drakes I have updated with headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that the jQuery with jsonp is expecting some JSON back. Your response body should then look like

```
jQuery21309164826604537666_1429167109185({});
```

In PHP you can simply return a dummy function like this:

```
$callback = isset($_GET["callback"]) ? $_GET["callback"] : "?";
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo $callback . "({});";
```

For Node.js, you can just use

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
res.jsonp({});
```

Ref: [ExpressJS JSONP](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.jsonp)

Comment: Not working...I'm using nodejs in the backend, I set the headers using res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html"); and the response body looks like this jQuery21308786661834456027_1429179942244({}); But still the same error happens..

Comment: You cannot hard code `jQuery21309164826604537666_1429167109185` like that. It's a random function name assigned by jQuery. Also, set content type to `application/json`.

Comment: I didnt hard code that.. if (req.query.hasOwnProperty('callback')) {
 var callbackParam = req.query.callback; 
 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
 res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
 callback = callbackParam + "({});";
 }
 console.log(callback);
This is the code

Comment: Good man! And when you type your URL into the browser, what is the body contents that result?

Comment: Browser says  "Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Comment: That's the response when you typed the URL directly in the browser? What happens when you browse a similar URL on the same server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75394/discussion-between-im-nidhin-and-drakes).